# Can someone explain x and y in this "function factory"?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, currying

From [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) on closures:

```
function makeAdder(x) {
  return function(y) {
    return x + y;
  };
}

var add5 = makeAdder(5);
var add10 = makeAdder(10);

console.log(add5(2));  // 7
console.log(add10(2)); // 12
```

I can't understand how in `makeAdder(5)` the parameter is received as `x`, but in `add5(2)` it is `y`.

I would expect it to say `y is undefined` both times.  Can anyone explain how it works the way it does?

Comment: I just realized it can be called like `makeAdder(5)(2)` which now makes sense, but I'll leave the question in case someone can explain it for future users.

Comment: This is also known as currying. The exact same code can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314/what-is-currying

Comment: this is a duplicated question of another...

Comment: @Endless then tag it as such with a link to the other question?

Comment: There is no way that is a duplicate question.  Even if I had found that, it would only have confused me further.  It is way more complex and references third party libraries and paradigms (arrow functions) not even mentioned here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `makeAdder()` it returns a function (not a value). Therefore to use it, you would have something like

```
makeAdder(4)(5)
```

This would add 4 to 5 and return 9. Again, `makeAdder()` here returns another function, which is why I called an argument after it (`(5)`).

If you would like to read further, this is a concept in JavaScript which is called currying. It is a functional programming technique.

Comment: That is so nice to hear. Thank you very.

Answer (score 1):

When calling `add5 = makeAdder(5);` essentially what is happening is:

```
add5 = function(y){
    return 5 + y;
}
```

At this point `add5(y)` will give you `y + 5`.

As you've noticed from your comment you can use `makeAdder(x)(y)`, this essentially does the same thing, it boils down to:

```
(function(y){return x + y})(y);
```

Answer (score 0):

`makeAdder` takes a parameter `x`, and *returns a function* that can see `x` (google: "closure") and also takes its own parameter, `y`.